# A doubt on a multivariable calculus result

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. $U$ open. Is it true that for any $v = ( \alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_d ) \in \mathbb{R}^d $, we have

$$ D_v f(x_0) = \sum_{j=1}^d \alpha_j \frac{ \partial f }{\partial  x_j}(x_0)?$$

Comment: Why would you doubt that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Definition of differentiability**: $f: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if there exists a linear map $J: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ --that is, $J(h) = \sum \limits_{j=1}^{d} a_j h_j$ for some $a_1, \dots, a_d \in \mathbb R$-- such that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - J(h)}{||h||} = 0$$

**Observation**: The above limit is $0$ as $h$ goes to $0$ through any path and in particular through any line, that is, when $h = tu$ with $u \in \mathbb R^d$ fixed and $t \to 0$.

Now let $u \in \mathbb R^d$, $u \neq 0$; we have

$$\begin{align}
D_u f(x_0) &= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + tu) - f(x_0)}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + tu) - f(x_0) - J(tu) + J(tu)}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + tu) - f(x_0) - J(tu)}{t} + \frac{J(tu)}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + tu) - f(x_0) - J(tu)}{t||u||}||u|| + \frac{J(tu)}{t}
\end{align}$$

By the above observation, the first term goes to $0 \cdot ||u|| = 0$ as $t \to 0$, whereas $$ \frac{J(tu)}{t} = \frac{\sum \limits_{j = 1}^{d} a_j t u_j}{t} = \frac{t \sum \limits_{j = 1}^{d} a_j u_j}{t} = \sum \limits_{j = 1}^{d} a_j u_j = J(u)$$ Hence we have $$D_u f(x_0) = 0 + J(u) = J(u)$$

In particular, if $u = e_j$, we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x_0) = D_{e_j}f(x_0) = J(e_j) = a_j$$

Therefore $$D_v f(x_0) = J(v) = \sum \limits_{j = 1}^{d} a_j \alpha_j = \sum \limits_{j = 1}^{d}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x_0) \alpha_j = \sum \limits_{j = 1}^{d} \alpha_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x_0)$$

---

"**Old proof**": if $f$ is differentiable then $$f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) = \langle \nabla f(x_0), h \rangle + o(||h||)$$

as $||h|| \to 0$. Substituting $h = tv$ and dividing by $t$ we get $$\frac{f(x_0 + tv) - f(x_0)}{t} = \langle \nabla f(x_0), v \rangle + ||v|| \frac{o(|t|)}{t}$$

And as $t \to 0$ $$D_v f(x_0) = \langle \nabla f(x_0), v \rangle = \sum_{j=1}^d \alpha_j \frac{ \partial f }{\partial  x_j}(x_0)$$

Comment: You do not need $x_0+v \in U$.  $x_0$ is in $U$, and $v$ is in the tangent space to $U$ at $x_0$.  Your limit involves $f(x_0+tv)$ for small values of $t$, and these are all eventually in $U$.

Comment: @StevenGubkin that's true!

Comment: I don't understand the first part. Are you assuming that $Df(x_0) = < \nabla f(x_0), h > $ ?? if so, why is that true ??

Comment: Can you explain more your answer? So that I can award you the 150 points? thanks a lot

Comment: @Mann The first line is a consequence of the definition of differentiability. I've edited my answer; I'm now using wikipedia's definition of differentiability and I've also added more details.

Answer (score 2):

When $f$ is differentiable at $p$ then there exists a function $r$ with $\lim_{X\to 0}r(X)=0$, such that for some $h>0$ one has 
$$f(p+X)-f(p)=df(p).X +|X|\,r(X) \qquad\bigl(0<|X|<h\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$
Let a vector $V\ne0$ be given and put $X:=tV$ in $(1)$. Then we obtain
$$f(p+tV)-f(p)=t\> df(p).V +t\,|V|\>r(tV)\qquad\bigl(0<t<h'\bigr)\ .$$
It follows that
$$D_Vf(p):=\lim_{t\to0+}{f(p+tV)-f(p)\over t}=df(p).V+|V|\lim_{t\to 0+}r(tV)=df(p).V=\nabla f(p)\cdot V\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

This follows by applying the chain rule to the function $f\circ p$, where $p(t)=x_0+tv$. Note that $D_vf(x_0)=(f\circ p)'(0)$, this may even be the definition.