# Show that the function is differentiable

Tags: calculus

http://www.ladda-upp.se/bilder/cpreyimyyrfkn/ (here is the question, i couldnt upload the picture, just didnt work out)

Definition:
Supposed $E$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R^n}$, $f$ maps $E$ into $\mathbb{R^m}$ and $x \in E$. If there exist a linear transformation $A$ from $\mathbb{R^n}$ to $\mathbb{R^m}$ such that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x) - Ah} {h} = 0$$

Then we say that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and we write $$f´(x) = A$$

I couldnt make "fat letters" above, observe that $h \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Can anyone help me with this one, i tried to calculate the limit $$lim_{(h_1,h_2) \to (0,0)} \frac {(h_{1}^2 + 2h_1, h_{2}^2 + 4h_2)} {(h_1,h_2)}$$ Is this wrong ?

Comment: you are dividing wrongly, non senselessly

Comment: where am i dividing wrong? could you show me how the calculation should be carried out?

Comment: you can't divide pairs of real number just like you want... instead check this and the answers: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689609/a-doubt-on-a-multivariable-calculus-result to start to have an idea

Comment: The linear transformation $A$, as described above, is it a simple number or a matrix?

Comment: it is a 2-by-2 matrix, it is $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2x&0\\0&2y\end{array}\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is critical to keep track of what dimensions $x$, $h$, and $A$ have.

Recall that if $f$ is differentiable, then the derivative of $f$ at $x = (x_1,x_2)$ is given by the Jacobian evaluated at that point, which makes your transformation $\mathrm{A}: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ a 2 by 2 matrix. Since $h$ itself is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, carrying out matrix multiplication will make $\mathrm{A}h$ again a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now, since you are finding the derivative of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, you must actually evaluate the slightly different limit
$$
\lim_{(h_1, h_2) \to (0,0)} \frac{||f(x_1 + h_1, x_2 + h_2) - f(x_1, x_2) - \mathrm{A}h||}{||(h_1, h_2)||},
$$
where $||\cdot||: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is the Euclidean norm. (This makes both the numerator and denominator real numbers, so that the fraction represents a well-defined quotient.)

If you get zero when you evaluate this limit, you're good to go -- you'll have shown that $Df(x_1,x_2) = A$.

Here is a helpful blog post on the total derivative:

http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/the-total-derivative/

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped alot. However, you say that "if you get zero when you evaluate this limit...", when i evaluate the limit, what is A in the limit? An aribitary 2x2 matrix that iam supposed to determine or what?

Comment: The Jacobian of $f$ is exactly the matrix of partial derivatives of $f$ that janmarqz points out. To get $\mathrm{A}$, just evaluate the Jacobian matrix with $(x,y) = (1,2)$.